# How to update a value from table accessed via foreign key django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models

My DB models looks similar to this

```
class Leave(models.Model):
    available_leaves = models.IntegerField(default = 8)

class Policy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=7)

class StudentLeave(models.Model):
    leave = models.ForeignKey(Leave, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    policy = models.ForeignKey(Policy, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to deduct the leave of the student from here,
I have tried this

```
leave = Leave.objects.filter(pk = 1).first()
policy = Policy.objects.filter(pk = 1).first()
student = Student.objects.filter(name = 'matthew').first() 
studentleave = StudentLeave.objects.filter(student = student, policy = policy, leave = leave).first()
```

Now I have studentleave object through which I can access every table connected to this table.
So I have tried accessing this

```
studentleave.leave.available_leaves-=1 # Tried reducing it by one
print(studentleave.leave.available_leaves) #prints as 7 as expected because 8 is default
```

**But when I access the same model again, it's value is still 8 (old value)
I have tried update and save method on `studentleave.leave.update() and studentleave.update()` which are basically throwing error because that object has no attribute update**

How can I save those new values for them.

Thanks in advance for spending your time to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

To save changed data into database, one should use [`.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects) method of the model instance. So what you need is to call `studentleave.leave.save()`, which will perform an `UPDATE` sql query into database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get` method to get data from db via primary key. `Get` method return only one value from db if it exists.